# How to make animation in *.gif run only once in Qt?

Tags: qt, gif, animated-gif, qmovie

Is that possible in Qt? I did have a search here but no answer.

Comment: Does the .gif file itself have the loop count set to "infinite" or just 1?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html#loopCount